# How can I obtain all partitions of a list in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

By partition of a list, I mean a set of subsets of the list elements such that the intersection of any distinct pair of subsets is empty, and the union of all subsets is equal to the original list.

For example, if my input list is `{1,π,x}` then I'd like a function that returns

```
{ {{1},{π},{x}}, {{1,π},{x}}, {{1,x},{π}}, {{1},{x,π}}, {{1,π,x}} }
```

Comment: @yoda: The OP might be confused with the terminology. These aren't partitions, I agree.

Comment: @Blender Yeah, I just realized that he might be getting at something else.

Comment: @Blender, yoda: These are [partitions in the sense of sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set), just not in the sense of the Mathematica command [Partition](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Partition.html).

Comment: @Simon I know, and I didn't confuse that. The question wasn't clear at first to me and I thought he meant each of `{{1},{π},{x}}, {{1,π},{x}}`, etc to be the subsets that he was interested in and my comment was that the intersection of these two is not empty. Upon a second reading, I understood what he meant, and withdrew my comment.

Comment: @yoda: OK. Sometimes deletable comments can be confusing!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using adapted code from [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180110063111/http://mathforum.org/advanced/robertd/bell.html)

```
BellList[1] = {{{1}}};
BellList[n_Integer?Positive] := Join @@
  (ReplaceList[#,
    {{b___, {S__}, a___} :> {b, {S, n}, a},
     {S__} :> {S, {n}}}
   ] & /@ BellList[n - 1])

s = {a, b, c, d, e};

bell = BellList@Length@s /. n_Integer :> s[[n]]
```

---

Or, unsurprisingly, the [Combinatorica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Combinatorica/guide/CombinatoricaPackage.html) package has this function ([SetPartitions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Combinatorica/ref/SetPartitions.html)) already!

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]

comb = SetPartitions[{a, b, c, d, e}]
```

check that they both return the same result (but in different orders)

```
Complement[bell, comb] == {}
Sort@bell == Sort@comb
(* Both of the above return True *)
```

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, that's going to take me a little while to parse mentally, but as far as I can tell it does the job, thanks!

Comment: @Michael, I forgot to check for this function in the standard libraries.  See the update I just made.

Comment: Just upvoted 3 posts. You're now at 1000 for the tag! Enjoy your gold badge when the day rolls over :)

Comment: @yoda Thank you very much! :-D

Answer (score 2):

I would start with a [Powerset](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSet.html) of the set (use `Subsets[x]`) and then filter out the ones where `Union[x]` of the set is not the original set.

A bit slow, but I find it intuitive.

Comment: Union of `{{1,x},{π}}` is not the original set; though the OP asked for it.

Comment: @BillyONeal why do you say that the union {1,x} and {π} is not equal to {1,π,x}? The order of the elements of a set does not matter to the definition of the set...